# Find sum based on particular row id in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have  an asp.net Gridview which is having following columns and rows. The image has been attached

[image]

I am trying to find sum of quantities based on particular `Item ID`. In this case 57,53 & 91.

Comment: A loop, an if and some math, or some Linq will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowDataBound event for that.

```
//create a variable outside the rowdatabound method
int total_sum = 0;

protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //or if a list<object> is bound to the gridview
        //MyClass row = e.Row.DataItem as MyClass;

        //cast the correct column to an int and add it to the total
        total_sum += Convert.ToInt32(row["itemid"]);
    }
    else if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
    {
        //show results. this wil work even if the footer is not shown
        Label1.Text = string.Format("{0:N0}", total_sum);
    }
}
```